# JNativeHook doesn't work with Jython (JES)

Tags: java, jython, jes, jnativehook

I was trying to implement JNativeHook on jython, using JES.

I tried using JNativeHook on pure Java, and it does work as expected, yet, the same thing on jython throws an exception.

The exception `NoClassDefFoundError` occurs on `GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook()`.

Why is that?

P.S. I checked the `java.library.path` of both Java and Jython, and they are the exact same.

Edit: 
Tested some more and found out that the whole `GlobalScreen` class throws `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions when using its methods.

Edit 2:
Doing `dir(GlobalScreen)` jython can actually see the methods of the class, yet exceptions get thrown on use.

Comment: "the same thing on jython throws an exception". What exception is that?

Comment: On JES it throws "NullPointerException", on jython from shell it throws "UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? See [mcve].

Comment: In JES just `import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen` and try `GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook()`